# htaccess 404 is working only on file level but not folder level

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am using this rule to redirect to 404 while there is no such a file on the server

```
    RewriteEngine on
    ErrorDocument 404 mydomain.com/404
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

this is working fine on for example

> `mydomain.com/no-exiting-file`

but not functioning when I have

> `mydomain.com/no-exiting-folder/` or
> `mydomain.com/no-exiting-folder/no-exiting-file`

How can I fix this to cover not only the none existing file but even the none existing folders as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written based on your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
ErrorDocument 404 mydomain.com/404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```